# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql

```
insert_into tb_loan (Product_Code, Customer_Code, Loan_Amount, Rate_Interest, Amount_Tenure, Emi_Amount, Emi_Start, Emi_End) VALUES (0,0,'10000',10.37,'20','546.6','25-10-2013','25-10-2013')
```

> Failed to insert :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert_into tb_loan (Product_Code, Customer_Code, Loan_Amount, Rate_Interest, Am' at line 1

Comment: You Are inserting one value less in your query instead of 8 values you are only inserting 7 values.

Comment: no...am inserting 8 values oly..

Comment: Please phrase a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
insert_into
```

with

```
insert into
```

And better use the `YYYY-MM-DD` date format

```
insert into tb_loan (Product_Code, Customer_Code, Loan_Amount, Rate_Interest, Amount_Tenure, Emi_Amount, Emi_Start, Emi_End) 
VALUES (0,0,'10000',10.37,'20','546.6','2013-10-25','2013-10-25')
```

Comment: why?what s d diffrnt b/w using yyyy-mm-dd and dd-mm-YYYY?

Comment: It depends on the settings of your DB what format is accepted. `YYYY-MM-DD` is the default.

Comment: am selecting d date using date picker tats y its displying lyk tat...while inserting i ill explode "-" and convert date to system date format..

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query is wrong, try this

```
INSERT INTO tb_loan(Product_Code, Customer_Code, Loan_Amount, Rate_Interest, Amount_Tenure, Emi_Amount, Emi_Start, Emi_End) VALUES (0,0,'10000',10.37,'20','546.6','25-10-2013','25-10-2013')
```

Replace `insert_into` with `INSERT INTO`